# What is the difference between total order relations and well order relations?

Tags: relations

I know it has to be a partial order relation in order for it to be a well order relation or total order relation, but what are the differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order):

> In mathematics, a *well-order* (or well-ordering or well-order relation) on a set $S$ is a total order on $S$ with the property that every non-empty subset of $S$ has a least element in this ordering.

In particular, a well-order is a total order (which itself is a partial order).

But the other implication is not true: for instance, take the (natural) order on $\mathbb{Z}$. It is a total order, yet *not* a well-order — since in particular $\mathbb{Z}$ has no least element.

[image]

Comment: What would this diagram look like if it included circles for all six of strict well-orders, non-strict well-orders, strict total orders, non-strict total orders, strict partial orders, and non-strict partial orders?